# Couldn't find postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf files in my postgresql installation

Tags: centos, rhel, software-installation, postgresql

Following all the instructions from [UNIXMEN](http://www.unixmen.com/postgresql-9-4-released-install-centos-7/), installed `postgresql-9.4` in `CentOS 6.4`. Everything went well, started the service and could access `pgsql` screen. But when I try to configure the `phpPgAdmin`, I couldn't find the files

- postgresql.conf
- pg_hba.conf
- config.inc.php
- phpPgAdmin.conf

The instructions says, `postgresql` home directory will sit in `/etc/../` and some say it will be in `/var/lib/`. Where does the directory gets created (in CentOS)?

Is installation directory path is different in centos, redhat(RHEL7) & ubuntu?

**Update:** 
I ran a quick locate command for *postgresql.conf** and *hba.conf**, I found the sample files as `postgresql.conf.sample` and `pg_hba.conf.sample` (at `/usr/pgsql-9.4/share/` )

Comment: Is there a postgres user? Can you try: `sudo su - postgres`? That will take you right to the postgres home directory and you should be able to locate the pg_hba.conf file...Usually in RHEL/CentOS it would be in /var/lib/psql/ or something of that nature...

Comment: awesome.. there it is, now I can see the files. But what is the reason that they didn't appear when I executed locate command?? @ryekayo

Comment: that i'm not too sure of.. What was the command you did with locate?

Comment: locate *.conf*/ *.conf / .conf* were the command that I used.

Comment: Well i would recommend using find for one, since you do have the file name...But if what i suggested solved your problem I will go ahead and add that as answer.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you type the following:

`sudo su - postgres`

after installing postgresql-server, that should take you right to the home directory of postgres and will have the configuration files you are looking for. Usually in a RHEL environment, the configuration files would be stored in `/var/lib/pgsql/`. On my test environment it is stored in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data`.

Comment: Saved my day. It's working for postgres 9.2

Comment: In CentOS 7.6.1810 version is ommitted: `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf` and postgres home folder falls one folder short: `/var/lib/pgsql`

Answer (score 10):

I am in CenOS 7, `locate` is not installed by default. Similar to the answer above, but run with `show` cmd below:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'show config_file'
```

And find the files are in `/data/pgdata/postgresql.conf`.

Comment: in kubuntu v20.04 i used ```
sudo updatedb 
sudo locate pg_hba.conf
```

Answer (score 9):

Use linux command `locate`  (Docs: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html)

```
[root@CENTOS7 pgsql]# locate pg_hba.conf
/usr/pgsql-10/share/pg_hba.conf.sample
/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: yes. in kubuntu v20.04 i used `sudo updatedb ` and `sudo locate pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Below query will help to find postgres configuration file.

```
postgres=# SHOW config_file;
             config_file
-------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

[root@node1 usr]# cd /var/lib/pgsql/data/
[root@node1 data]# ls -lrth
total 48K
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    4 Nov 25 13:58 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_twophase
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_snapshots
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 Nov 25 13:58 pg_serial
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres   36 Nov 25 13:58 pg_multixact
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  20K Nov 25 13:58 postgresql.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.6K Nov 25 13:58 pg_ident.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 4.2K Nov 25 13:58 pg_hba.conf
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres   60 Nov 25 13:58 pg_xlog
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   18 Nov 25 13:58 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   18 Nov 25 13:58 pg_clog
drwx------ 5 postgres postgres   41 Nov 25 13:58 base
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   92 Nov 25 14:00 postmaster.pid
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   18 Nov 25 14:00 pg_notify
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   57 Nov 25 14:00 postmaster.opts
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   32 Nov 25 14:00 pg_log
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Nov 25 14:00 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   25 Nov 25 14:20 pg_stat_tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on CentOS 7 and I had to run initdb to generate postgresql.conf (and other) files.

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using CentOS7. For me, the command was:

```
$ su - postgres
$ su - postgres
$ psql postgres
# show config_file;
 /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
# \q
$ exit
$ exit
```

Answer (score -1):

you won't be able to find `pg_hba.conf` with the **locate** command because it is owned by postgres not root user. In my centos 7 `pg_hba.conf` was present at `/var/lib/pgsql/12/data`